# Laravel get collection of models where all relations has status = 2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I have a category model with a subcategory relationship. I need to get all categories in which all subcategories have the active status.
Please help me to form a query

I did

```
$query->whereHas('subcategory', function($query) {
            query->where('subcategory.status', '=', 'passed');
        });
```

but this query returns categories in which at least one subcategory is active, but I need all subcategories to be stranded, the status is active

Comment: post your model we can check the relationships

Comment: ```public function subcategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CategorySubcategory::class, 'category_id');
    }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would believe you would be able to do it with sub queries comparing the count of sub queries passed to the total. Had to asume the naming conventions, but you can tweak it to fit your tables.

```
$totalSubCategories = SubCategory::selectRaw('Count(subcategories.id) as totalc')
    ->whereColumn('categories.id', 'subcategories.parent_id');

$totalPassedSubCategories = SubCategory::selectRaw('Count(subcategories.id) as totalpassed')
    ->whereColumn('categories.id', 'subcategories.parent_id')
    ->where('status', 'passed');

Category::where($totalSubCategories, $totalPassedSubCategories)->get();
```

Comment: This is very raw and just to give you an idea, see if you can get it to work or else i must boot up an project and test the query :) Also i'm not certain how subqueries and where interacts, test it out and let's figure it out togheter.

Comment: thanks, I will try, if this is the answer to my question then I will mark it as an answer)